# How to properly connect Ajax/Javascript to the backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a PHP class that allows my users to `createAccount`, `updateAccount` along with various other functions.

I normally create an 'interface' script that initiates a class and calls the login function and I pass the variables from the front end to this script using JavaScript. However I have to create lots of these 'interface' scripts for each function. Is there any better way to do this?

I end up with an 'interface' folder which scripts such as `createAccount.php`, `updateAccount.php` and these scripts are called when the user wants to do any of these functions. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities for client-server communication. The method and design by which you choose to allow this communication is up to you.

As for your question - you can create a single php endpoint (i.e. `endpoint.php`) through which to handle all ajax requests. Specific parameters of the request, such as which server side action to perform, can be sent through the query parameters in the url (and accessed in your script with the `$_GET` variable), or through post data (and accessed with `$_POST`).

Assuming you are using jQuery, an AJAX request to this endpoint might look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/endpoint.php',
    data: {
        _function: 'createAccount',
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

And in `endpoint.php` you may handle the request in such a manner:

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['_function']){
    case 'createAccount':
        // handle account creation
        // ...
        break;
    case '...':
        // ...
}
?>
```

This is just one possibility of communication between client and server. No matter how you do it - with a single endpoint which handles all requests, or multiple endpoints - it's your design decision.

You might want to look up on client-server communication protocols over HTTP, such as REST and SOAP.

Comment: Smart, smart thinking I like it going to try that. Just saves me having a folder full of pretty much useless scripts!